# Bootstrap prevent nav-dropdown closing on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fighting with this pice of code for some time and any of the solutions I would find has't worked.

I want to prevent my menu closing after clicking on one of the links. My code:

```
 <li class="nav-dropdown">
                <a href="#" title="Menu Levels">
                    <i class="fa  fa-fw fa-folder-open"></i> Manage Devices
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("AddWizard", "Device")" id="Test">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw icon-plus"></i> Add Device
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("RemoveDevice", "Device")" >
                            <i class="fa fa-fw icon-close"></i> Remove Device
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

I've been trying tricks with stop propagating. For example this is not working for me:

```
  $('#Test').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        console.log("TEST");
        return false;
    });
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: When you click on any of those links you're requesting a new page from the server, which means, any attempt to keep it open with javascript is redundant. You'll have to open it on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use click function.

`$('#Test').on('hide.bs.dropdown'...` It doesn't work because `#Test` isn't a dropdown menu.

```
$('#Test').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // or return false
});
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/VjdNBA)**